# How to establish Lord Vishnu's idol in the home mandir?

Tags: gods, rituals

I am planning to get a new Lord Vishnu idol to worship in the home mandir. What is the correct and auspicious procedure to establish the new Lord Vishnu idol in the home mandir ? Can we touch the new idol to a Lord Vishnu idol in a big temple to mark as a sign of bringing Lord Vishnu home from the temple ?